# Oracle (or general sql) query to get 2 independent averages and counts from a simple table

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I do something like:

```
SELECT myKey, avg(x), avg(y), count(x), count(y)
from t
where x is not null
  and y is not null
group by myKEY
```

On the table

TABLE t

```
MyKey,X,Y
K1,null,1
K2,null,1
K3,3,2
K4,4,3
K5,4,null
K6,4,null
```

basically I would like to get the 2 averages and 2 counts in 1 query if possible (table is big).  This is  to run some analysis on some observations where the observations (X,Y) are independent.

however the averages and counts are independent since I need to exclude the nulls from the column.

Comment: What is the issue with your query?  And, what results do you want to get from your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT myKey, avg(x), avg(y), count(x), count(y)
from t
where x is not null and y is not null
group by myKEY;
```

will return values only for rows where `x` and `y` are both not-null (the 3rd and 4th rows in your example data).

If you want the values from all rows, just remove the `where` clause:

```
SELECT myKey, avg(x), avg(y), count(x), count(y)
from t
group by myKEY;
```

The `avg()` and `count()` functions will ignore `NULL` values.

Comment: yes removing the null check worked, so simple! I thought I needed some subqueries, but this worked!